# Calculating $\nabla\left(\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{r}_{0} e^{i\boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

- In a longer derivation I ran into the following quantity:
  $$
  \nabla\left[\nabla\cdot\left(%
  {\bf r}_{0}\,{\rm e}^{{\rm i}{\bf k} \cdot {\bf r}}\,\right)
  \right]
  $$
  ( i.e., the gradient of the divergence ) where ${\bf k}$ is a vector of constants and ${\bf r}$ is a position vector.
- Can someone help explaining how to calculate this?
  I am hoping it gives:
  $$
  \nabla\left[\nabla\cdot\left(%
  {\bf r}_{0}\,{\rm e}^{{\rm i}{\bf k} \cdot {\bf r}}\,\right)
  \right] =
  -{\bf k}\left({\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}_{0}\right)
  $$
  ( because then the rest of my equations add up ).

Comment: That quantity inside looks like a scalar, how is the divergence being taken?

Comment: Yes, it was a notational mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Summing over repeated indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), the divergence is $r_{0i}\partial_ie^{\text{i}k_jr_j}=r_{0i}\text{i}k_ie^{\text{i}k_jr_j}=\text{i}(k\cdot r_0)e^{\text{i}k_jr_j}$. Applying $\partial_l$ pulls down another $\text{i}k_l$ factor, so the gradient is $-k(k\cdot r_0)e^{\text{i}k\cdot r}$. Your desired result drops the exponential, which I suspect is a typo.

Comment: I was missing an $i$, you are correct. The equations are correct now.

Comment: @Jacob I saw that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: My desired result should have the exponential, so now it looks like it adds up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\nabla\bracks{%
\nabla\cdot\pars{{\bf r}_{0}\expo{\ic{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}}}}} =
\nabla\bracks{%
\overbrace{\pars{\nabla\cdot{\bf r}_{0}}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}\
\expo{\ic{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}} +
{\bf r}_{0}\cdot\nabla\pars{\expo{\ic{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}}}} =
\ic\nabla\pars{{\bf r}_{0}\cdot{\bf k}\,\expo{\ic{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\,{\bf r}_{0}\cdot{\bf k}\,\nabla\expo{\ic{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}} =
\ic\,{\bf r}_{0}\cdot{\bf k}\,\pars{\expo{\ic{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}}
\,\ic{\bf k}} =
\bbx{-{\bf k}\pars{{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}_{0}}\expo{\ic{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}}}
\\ &
\end{align}
There are a [lot of vectorial identities over here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.6).

Comment: Thank you, that makes it very clear.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks.